# XCTest for test model objects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

Bellow i have mentioned my model object.

```
class HVConnection: NSObject {

    //private var _data: NSMutableDictionary
    private var _data: NSMutableDictionary

    // MARK:- Init

    init(data: NSDictionary)
    {
        _data = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: data)
    }

    // MARK:- Properties
    var last_name: String? {
        if let lastNameObject = _data.objectForKey("last_name") {
            return (idObject as! String)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

then i implemented a test case to check variables.
Bellow i have mentioned the test case.

```
func testNetworkModelObject() {

    let connectionObject = ["network": ["first_name": "Dimuth", "last_name": "Lasantha", "business_email": "example@gmail.com", "currency": "USD", "language": "en-us", "category": "individual"]]
    let modelObject = HVConnection(data: connectionObject)

    XCTAssertEqual(modelObject.last_name, "Lasantha")
}
```

bellow i have mentioned the error

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional("Lasantha")")

please help me to fix the issue

Comment: When you create the modelObject, and you do `modelObject.last_name` does it return the proper value? I think maybe the dictionary you are passing it only has one key/value with ''network"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot use

```
_data.objectForKey("last_name")
```

in your `HVConnection` because it is nested within another dictionary key called `network`.

So instead use:

```
// MARK:- Properties
var last_name: String? {
    if let lastNameObject = _data.objectForKey("network")?.objectForKey("last_name") {
        return (lastNameObject as! String)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is to demonstrate the dictionaries in use:

```
["network": // your dictionary is a dictionary within a dictionary
    ["first_name": "Dimuth", 
     "last_name": "Lasantha", 
     "business_email": "example@gmail.com", 
     "currency": "USD", 
     "language": "en-us", 
     "category": "individual"]
]
```

In order to get your `last_name`, you have to get the dictionary for key `network` to get the actual dictionary, and once you have that, you can check that dictionary you get back from the `network` key for the key `last_name`.